# How do I parse string which contains # character?

Tags: rebol

```
parse copy text [ to "<#@" to "#>"]
```

This causes my Rebol script to generate a syntax error.

Comment: Please give more context. As is easily verifiable, the given line of code alone does not result in a syntax error (just checked with 2.7.8.4.2).

Comment: No syntax error either on R3 nor R2. It works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

parse copy text [ to {<#@} to {#>}]

I didn't test the code, but I think it works.

--DJ